# names above the numbers of a numerical vector in R. how to change them?

Tags: r, numeric

in R there were several times on which a numerical vector had names before each numeric value as this:

```
class(oral_NO_AR_comp$clustering$clust1)
```

output: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1rf6.png) "numeric"

and the content looks like this:

[image]

THe point here is that I need to change the names of the strings above the numbers, is there a way to do that?r

Comment: You can get those names with `names(oral_NO_AR_comp$clustering$clust1)`. You can use `names(oral_NO_AR_comp$clustering$clust1)<- <whatever you want>` to change the names if you like.  You can also use `unname()` to remove the names if you want.

Comment: @MrFlick, please post as an answer?

Comment: @BenBolker Surely there must be a dup for this, no? I was a bit too lazy to search myself.

Comment: Maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609077/r-changing-the-names-in-a-named-vector or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735335/changing-vector-names

Comment: I guess the second one (although really this question is a little more basic than those questions: I think your comment-as-answer would be useful even if this gets marked as a dup)

Comment: Including `setNames` in the answer might be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

You can get those names with

```
names(oral_NO_AR_comp$clustering$clust1).
```

You can use

```
names(oral_NO_AR_comp$clustering$clust1)<- <whatever you want> 
# or
setNames(oral_NO_AR_comp$clustering$clust1, <whatever you want)
```

to change the names if you like. You can also use remove the names with

```
unname(oral_NO_AR_comp$clustering$clust1)
```

Note that these functions (with the exception of `names<-`) do not change the original value, they return a new value. If you want to replace the original value, be sure to assign it `<-` to the original variable.